# Confusion in calculating Bessel functions

Tags: solution-verification, bessel-functions

Let $J_0$ be a (zeroth order, first kind) Bessel function so that, according to https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/02/02/0006/, $$\int _0^\infty t\hspace {1mm}J_0(at)J_0(bt)\hspace {2mm}dt=0\hspace {10mm}\text {for any real $a,b>0$ and $a\not =b$}$$ $$\int _0^\infty t\hspace {1mm}J_0(at)J_0(bt)\hspace {2mm}dt=\frac {1}{a}\hspace {10mm}\text {for any real $a,b>0$ and $a=b$}.$$

Therefore, for any (integrable over $(0,\infty )$) function $w$,$$\int _0^\infty \int _0^\infty w(x)w(x')\int _0^\infty t\hspace {1mm}J_0(\sqrt xt)J_0(\sqrt {x'}t)\hspace {2mm}dtdxdx'=\int _0^\infty \frac {w(x)^2}{\sqrt x}dx.$$

But the LHS is also $$4\int _0^\infty \int _0^\infty yy'w(y^2)w(y'^2)\int _0^\infty t\hspace {1mm}J_0(yt)J_0(y't)\hspace {2mm}dtdydy'=4\int _0^\infty yw(y^2)^2dy=4\int _0^\infty w(x)^2dx.$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,first for all positive real $a$ and $b$,

$$\int_0^\infty xJ_0(ax)J_0(bx)\,dx=\frac{\delta(a-b)}{a}$$

Thus,

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty w(x)w(x') \frac{\delta(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x'})}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\,dx'=2\int_0^\infty w^2(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Mark, in your final integral is $w$, is $dw\, dw'$ correct?

Comment: Can you explain the last equality or give the definition of $\delta (a-b)$?

Comment: @tomos Note that $\delta$ denotes the Dirac Delta.

Comment: What is $w'$? Is $w$ supposed to be $x$?

Comment: @Gary There is no $w'$.

Comment: There is one in $$\frac{\delta(\sqrt{w}-\sqrt{w'})}{\sqrt{w}}.$$

Comment: @Gary Fixed.  Thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that $a=\sqrt x$ and not $\sqrt{w(x)}$ in the question.

Comment: ah ok, so i've not interpreted/understood $\delta (x)$ correctly. thanks!

Comment: @Gary Yes.  This shows the dangers of posting a solution while at a gym and while using a phone.  I've corrected things. The result was correct. ;-))

Comment: @tomos Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: i've upvoted and accepted the answer. (your answer did help me, but i don't think it shows what i was doing wrong or addresses what i wasn't understanding (it's not a big deal, in the meantime i realised the $\delta $ function wasn't just simply a 1 or 0 function))